# My program has stopped and I don'y know why

Tags: java, android, xml, initialization

My program;

```
    package com.google.tictactoe;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    public class TicTacToe extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.play_ground);
    }
    }

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/board">
    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

When I remove `android:background="@drawable/board"` then the program is fine. And I have same problem when I add images to start the game.

When I start the program logcat is as below:

```
03-30 00:36:57.477 14952-14952/com.google.tictactoe E/AndroidRuntime:        FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.tictactoe, PID: 14952
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.tictactoe/com.google.tictactoe.TicTacToe}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.google.tictactoe.TicTacToe.onCreate(TicTacToe.java:12)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.google.tictactoe.TicTacToe.onCreate(TicTacToe.java:12) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.google.tictactoe.TicTacToe.onCreate(TicTacToe.java:12) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.google.tictactoe:drawable/board" (7f060056) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060056 a=-1 r=0x7f060056}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2602)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3948)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:573)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:203)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:199)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:195)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.google.tictactoe.TicTacToe.onCreate(TicTacToe.java:12) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: It's hard to answer this. Did you try other images? or where is the board image? What do you mean program has stopped, it does not compile or crashes on start?

Comment: Yes I tried other images but the result is same. I post an image "board.png" in drawable folder and program crashes on start.

Comment: Show us the crash log.

Comment: You mean logcat !

Comment: yes. the especially red text displayed. when you try to run the app.

Comment: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.google.tictactoe:drawable/board" (7f060056) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060056 a=-1 r=0x7f060056}.. Something is wrong with your board.png. show my where you place the image. or is it even good PNG image? can you open it outside of android studio?

Comment: /Users/hojat/AndroidStudioProjects/TicTacToe/app/src/main/res/drawable-v24/board.png  and I can open it outside.

Comment: why is it in drawable-v24? Place it in main drawable folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments.